# Starting wordpress on nginx debian server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm stuck with the installation of Wordpress for Nginx on Debian. The website pointing to my server is mes-affaires.xyz.

Nginx logs are showing 200 responses for any URL from that domain, and appearing all blanks in my browser. That's the difficulty as I'm having no error log of any kind.

Any idea why it's doing this or where I could get a kind of error log?

Comment: Looks like PHP fatal error (missed PHP extension, for example), you can find it in PHP (folder /var/log/php-fpm or /var/log/php) or nginx error logs (folder /var/log/nginx). It is HTTP 500 usually, but better check logs.

Answer (score 0):

Now www.mes-affaires.xyz shows nginx default page.
Be sure u got config for your site, and u added it in nginx.conf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php-fpm, then you need right setting at server directive. For example:

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
```

Especially line

> fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

must have right configuration and causes white blank page in browser when its missconfigured. Also check

> $document_root

variable and ofcourse your log files.